# Time Query with DatePart function

Tags: sql, ms-access

Based on what I have read, I have created the following query to group everything by time, first by seconds and afterwards converting them into hh:mm:ss format:

```
SELECT Exits.Categorization, Format(Sum(DatePart("h",[Time_after_Search])*3600+DatePart("n",[Time_after_Search])*60)) AS TotalSeconds, Round([TotalSeconds]/3600,0) & ':' &  Right("00" &  Round(((TotalSeconds/3600) + Round(TotalSeconds/3600,0))*60,0),2) AS TotalTime
FROM Exits
GROUP BY Exits.Categorization;
```

The very strange thing is for some of the groupings the conversion between seconds and hh:mm:ss is exactly correct. Yet for other groups, I noticed it is mostly off by 1200 seconds when you convert seconds into hh:mm:ss format. Why in the world would that happen? Here is the result of my query so you can see. For example, if you see the first category, CAS Number work correctly. However chemical should yield 204360 instead of 203160 (I mean the hours equaivalent of that), etc

```
Categorization   TotalSeconds   TotalTime
                         1080   0:18
Brand Name              74880   21:08
CAS Number              37200   10:20
Catalog Numbers        522960   145:16
Chemical               203160   56:46
Generic Term            34860   10:81
Mistake???                  0   0:00
Product Characteristic 254640   71:04
Product Type           382560   106:36
Supplier Name           55560   15:26
Supplier Part Number   992160   276:96
```

Comment: perhaps when you divide, you are hitting rounding errors due to integer divide. Either cast the numbers to float inside the `ROUND()` function, or do without rounding somehow

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```

And then, in your query:

```
SELECT 
    Exits.Categorization, 
    Sum(DateDiff("s", #00:00#, [Time_after_Search])) AS TotalSeconds,
    FormatHourMinute(Sum([Time_after_Search])) AS TotalTime
FROM 
    Exits
GROUP BY 
    Exits.Categorization;
```

or perhaps:

```
SELECT 
    Exits.Categorization, 
    DateDiff("s", #00:00#, Sum([Time_after_Search])) AS TotalSeconds,
    FormatHourMinute(Sum([Time_after_Search])) AS TotalTime
FROM 
    Exits
GROUP BY 
    Exits.Categorization;
```

Comment: your saying that you can't do it using only a query in Access and no VBA? I have not used VBA in the past and was not particularly interested in using it.

Comment: No, I didn't say that, but using a function as shown is so much cleaner. I've added a minor change to my answer.

Comment: do you know of a way I can do it without invoking anything but queries? Something that would involve hopefully a minor change to the query that I already have in my question

Comment: Yes. You can modify it to use the two core lines in my function, but it will end up nearly as unreadably as your original query.